# Render showing different frames than sequencer

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I've hard cut a video to remove a section and pulled it together. In the sequencer/preview window the edit looks fine. When I render it, at least 1 second of the removed frames appear. Went to render image and the start of the second section rendered part of the cut frames. I've had this show up before where the rendered image was not the same as what was showing in the preview window. The frame number in the sequencer/preview is a different image from the render of the frame. Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the file. How did you pull the strips together? Did you move one strip as a whole to the other, or did you accidentally just move the start or end of a strip next to the other?

Comment: G then pulled it over, zoomed in until I could be sure it went from end of strip to start of then next strip in the next frame. I'm working on a game playthrough, a unwanted dialog popped up. cut the dialog section out, or so I thought, preview in the sequencer for the first frame shows the character, render image of the frame shows the dialog. Ok, just checked 1 second was a definite overstatement. It's about 5-7 frames difference before the render image catches up to what the preview is showing, but it is enough show visibly in the animated render.

Comment: I just thought you might have clicked on the start or the end of the strip and selected one of them (indicated by showing the frame number on start or end) instead of selected the complete strip. If you then move it with G, only the start or end will be moved, resulting in extending the strip in one or the other direction, which might reveal frames that you cut out beforehand. If it's not that, I really can't tell without having the files or at least seeing what you have done.

Comment: Well I ended up using render image to figure out where to make another cut, and the dialog is finally gone. I also used an overlay later in the video to hide some detail, and when I used the render image on it also discovered I was off by a couple of frames that only show in the render not in the preview window on the same frame number. This is going to be more work than I was expecting.

Comment: just my 2 cents, I've had this kind of problems in the past when the automatically generated proxies got out of sync with the actual video files. Had to go to the proxy folder and delete them to sort it out

Comment: OK. Removing the proxies did indeed solve the issue. The preview is matching the render exactly.